# SOAP (Error Fetching HTTP Headers) possibly due to corrupt interbase database?

Tags: php, soap, interbase

I have a soap service giving me trouble at a clients. One specific call to the API returns the error Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers

I've read enough to see that sometimes it's connection issues or execution time running out, but I tried extending run time to the moon to confirm and it doesn't work.

1) Same service version, two databases, one works, the client's one doesn't.

2) On the clients database, takes all other calls except the problem one.

3) Maybe the call and database structure is the problem? Nope, debug the app and the break point gets hit or missed at random depending on how long it takes for the fetch error to drop in.

So it's not a single point of reference in my procedure. I've seen in the past issues where corrupt DB could potentially cause the connection to it to jump, but I don't know how I could potentially investigate that.

I tried restoring a DB backup from the clients, as restoring sometimes fixes the icky stuff but no dice. Any suggestions what to look at next?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, once of the queries done to the database takes too much time and must jump off the connection.

Doesn't really make sense to me because if I put execution time to a million the whole call still never ends. I can still make it past the query aswell with debug before it crashes. So on a logical front I might be misunderstanding the order of operations, error catching or how a service and sql queries are handled, but optimizing one of the SQL queries to one that runs instantly has stopped giving me issues.